# Pycharm IntelliJ R extension cannot find R interpreter

Tags: r, pycharm

After opening a .R file in Pycharm and trying to run the R code, the error `R Console Failure: Cannot run console until path to viable R interpreter is specified` appears. The R language plugin is installed, as is R for the computer, but PyCharm File -Settings -Languages and Frameworks does not show R (screenshot [image: Screenshot of problems]). RStudio runs the R code in the file without problems. PyCharm used to run it, but after closing and reopening PyCharm, the file no longer runs.
I did the Edit Configurations that PyCharm asked and specified a .R configuration: the file is my open file that I want to run, the file directory is the working directory.
The file in question is an existing file initially created in RStudio. It is not a PyCharm project.
Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Latitude E 7470.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting PyCharm worked for me.

I was working on a Python project. Then I decided to change to an R project, opened it, and then opened some R files in PyCharm. That's when the error appeared.

I restarted PyCharm and upon reopening it, the R files were all there and the R console was working.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar problem.  I think the issue was that when I created the project in Pycharm.  I did not initially choose to create the project as an R Project or R Package.  Not sure if it's possibly to work around this if the project was initially designed with Python.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I am using an existing file created in RStudio, not a project. Good to know similar problems crop up when starting from PyCharm.

Comment: I imagine the design of PyCharm is so that you can use a python interpreter and R interpreter jointly within the project.  I was able to do that by created a Python interpreter available to all projects before created the R project.  Once created the R project, I chose the desired python interpreter within Settings.  It may also work if you add a python interpreter once created the R project or package.  What type of OS are you using?  I'm using LInuxMint 20.1

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Latitude E 7470. Python interpreter does not work for R, seems to be the default. The problem is I cannot add the R interpreter - no such option in Settings.

Comment: My guess is the issues are coming from the fact that the project was not initially linked with R when pycharm created the project folder.  Any changes relating to R still are not understood by the project folder.  Creating an entirely new project, and starting off with choosing it as an R project.  Then configuring a python interpreter, and copying all of the non-hidden files from your old project directory could possibly fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the R file to a folder with a previously working PyCharm project (with a main.R file) and then opening it in PyCharm, the code in the file ran. The problem was solved, but it reappeared after the computer went to sleep and was wakened.
The file in the folder of the working PyCharm project no longer ran, but generated the original error. Closing the file in PyCharm and reopening did not work. Closing PyCharm and then doubleclicking the file to open it and PyCharm together worked: the code in the file ran.